# Rails 5 fixture labeled reference for has_one not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, integration-testing, fixtures

Lesson and Availability are ActiveRecords with a has_one association. I made sure that their database tables have each other's _id as a column. In the console, I can access `Availability.first.lesson` and `Lesson.first.availability` without issue. However, when I write the following fixtures, I end up with `ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "lessons" has no column named "availability"`. The labeled references feature of fixtures works fine with `belongs_to`, and I expect it to work with has_one in the same fashion. How can I get it work?

```
#availabilities.yml
availability1:
  lesson: lesson1

#lessons.yml
lesson1:
  availability: availability1
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though ActiveRecord allows you to access `Availability.first.lesson` when you set up the has_one association on the Availability model, the database migration that backs up this association does not expect Availability to have any lesson related columns.

From https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association:
[image]

The [labeled references feature of Fixtures](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html#class-ActiveRecord::FixtureSet-label-Label+references+for+associations+-28belongs_to-2C+has_one-2C+has_many-29) therefore only works for models with a belongs_to association and not has_one or has_many.

This is a non answer and I would appreciate a more detailed under-the-hood explanation from rails experts.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @allenylzhou's answer, the reason why it only works on `belongs_to` associations is because the label references for associations depends on the foreign key, and the foreign key is always on the class with the `belongs_to` association.

[From https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html#class-ActiveRecord::FixtureSet-label-Label+references+for+associations+-28belongs_to-2C+has_one-2C+has_many-29)

> Specifying foreign keys in fixtures can be very fragile, not to mention difficult to read. Since Active Record can figure out the ID of any fixture from its label, you can specify FK's by label instead of ID.

[From API dock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods):

> The `#belongs_to` association is always used in the model that has the foreign key.